# Why does debug_backtrace() seem to skip over several important "steps", disabling me from debugging where a FATAL error origins?

Tags: php, error-handling, fatal-error, backtrace, debug-backtrace

My end goal is to be able to properly log "FATAL" errors, which are sadly not "seen" by `set_error_handler`.

Currently, all PHP does is log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65011744 bytes) in blablabla.php on line 27
```

That kind of log is virtually useless, since it only tells me the very last "point" where it died. That's why I use a custom error handler to log "all" errors with a `debug_backtrace()`. But since `set_error_handler` doesn't "get" FATAL errors, I found (on Stack Exchange) [an alleged way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-e-error-error) to handle those errors anyway, by registering a "shutdown function" which checks for the last error, makes a `debug_backtrace()` and logs that.

Sadly, when I try it, the `debug_backtrace()` seems to be very limited and does not include all the "steps" at all. Example:

```
function handle_critical_errors()
{
    $error_data = error_get_last();
    var_dump($error_data);
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}

function shutdown_handler_function()
{
    handle_critical_errors();
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown_handler_function');

function nonbroken_function()
{
    broken_function();
}

function broken_function()
{
    $buffer = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 999999999999999; $i++)
        $buffer .= 'this is intended to exhaust all availabile memory because trigger_error doesn\'t let me trigger a fatal error for unknown reasons';
}

nonbroken_function();
```

When I run this, this is outputted:

```
array(4) {
  ["type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["message"]=>
  string(83) "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65011744 bytes)"
  ["file"]=>
  string(54) "blablablabla.php"
  ["line"]=>
  int(27)
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(54) "blablablabla.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(12)
    ["function"]=>
    string(22) "handle_critical_errors"
    ["args"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["function"]=>
    string(25) "shutdown_handler_function"
    ["args"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

There is no mention of `broken_function()` or `nonbroken_function()`, even though these were called. I don't get it. Even though it's obvious what is causing the FATAL error in this minimal test/example, this is never or rarely the case in the "real world", where it will just point at a generic line somewhere in my complex system and the only "backtrace" consists of just the shutdown handler function and the error handler function. There is no real "context". I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Furthermore, I don't understand the point of `error_get_last()` to begin with since PHP logs the FATAL error by default anyway, but again, shows no context even if I use the backtrace function.

I've re-read the manual about the `debug_backtrace` function but it says very little about what a backtrace *is*. I thought I understood what it is, but apparently, I don't?

Is the "cut-off" backtrace perhaps somehow related to the fact that this is a FATAL error, and this makes even that basic function unable to operate properly? If such this the case, doesn't that mean that it's literally *impossible* to properly log (and thus debug) FATAL errors without pure guesswork/manual figuring of the code?

Comment: your answers are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-e-error-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I catch a PHP fatal (\`E\_ERROR\`) error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-e-error-error)

Comment: @andrewtweber
You both link to the question which was the basis of my question. They don't explain this at all.